# Typescript error:cannot find module 'webpack-bundle-analyzer'

Tags: typescript

When i run the command **gulp serve** i am getting the following error:
Typescript error:**cannot find module 'webpack-bundle-analyzer'**

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: you should update with what doest gulp serve does in your application. Most likely you did not install dependencies :D

Comment: I have uninstall all the npm commands and installed again.Now it is working fine.

Comment: But npm audit fix and npm audit command is not working.I am getting the following error:                                                                                            
 npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json